# Display decimal field without right side zeros

Tags: nodes

I have a decimal field for length (cm) with precision 2. If I enter number without '.' it should display as it is only. For example If I enter 23 it should display 23 only not 23.00. If I enter 23.14 it should display 23.14. How can I do that? Am I missing any thing here?

Sorry, editing my question:

It should display the numbers like following (in Full node view, Views, Forms and wherever it appears)

If any one entered 93 it should be displayed 93 only not 93.00 (cause of the scale 2).

If entered 93.40 it should be displayed 93.4

If entered 93.14 it should be displayed as 93.14 only

I know that the value will be saved with scale 2(As given in Fields Form) in the database. But the value should be displayed as a whole number etc

Comment: Yes you need to tell us where you are displaying it.  Is it on the node page?  in a view?

Answer (score 0):

You can format the field from Manage Display as follow:

1. Go to manage display of the respective entity
2. Click on settings button of the field to do formatting
3. Change the value of Scale dropdown to zero
4. Click update
5. Click Save button at bottom

[image]

Comment: This will permanently change the display to 0 decimal places.  OP wants this to occur only when the decimal places have a zero value.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same thing. After some experimenting, I found that if you can change the Decimal field to a **Float**, you can then select *Unformatted* display format. That shows whole numbers without the trailing decimal and zero.